# route traffic using the primary or secondary IP windows

Tags: windows, ip-routing

I have Primary address 192.168.1.238 which is mapped to our Public IP address 1 and secondary IP 192.168.1.138 mapped to another Public IP address 2. How can I configure static routing of my windows 2008 R2 to send traffic to specific IP address using secondary IP?

Appreciate your advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
route add -p Destination Gateway IF InterfaceIndex
```

(eg:   route add -p 10.168.173.107 10.168.172.1 if 24 )

Destination is the specific IP or subnet you want to access .

To get interfaceindex :

```
netsh int ipv4 show int
```